# Date Slider with current date selected

Tags: android, android-listview, android-datepicker, android-date

I am trying to make the UI for date Slider with date selection by the small arrow below.

How to go about it. Any help ?

[image]

Since the dates I will show would be of an array. Should I go with ListView.

Comment: There is one project on github named DateSlider by Daniel Berndt you can check it to start with https://github.com/bendemboski/DateSlider

Comment: If it still actual, maybe this will help to someone: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34049368/2450152